Existence compatible integrable complex structure
Let $(M,\omega)$ be a fixed symplectic manifold. There are lots of compatible almost complex structures, but is there a criterion to decide if any of them is integrable?
For example take $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (n>1) with some non-standard symplectic form, is there an integrable compatible complex structure?
